# In SQL return rows with max value for each group, including rows that have the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

How do I return rows with the max Value for each department and if two or more rows for the same Department have the same Value include those in the results?

For instance, I have the table below:

| Name | Code | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | ABC12 | 2020-05-12 | 15 |
| Finance | ABC12 | 2020-06-24 | 118 |
| Marketing | BBG43 | 2020-05-12 | 12 |
| Marketing | BBG43 | 2021-08-07 | 1 |
| Tech | PKY76 | 2020-07-21 | 7 |
| Tech | PKY76 | 2020-11-28 | 7 |

I want to return rows that have the maximum Value for each department. If a department has the same maximum Value on different days return all of those days.

For example, my desired output would be this:

| Name | Code | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | ABC12 | 2020-06-24 | 118 |
| Marketing | BBG43 | 2020-05-12 | 12 |
| Tech | PKY76 | 2020-07-21 | 7 |
| Tech | PKY76 | 2020-11-28 | 7 |

So far I have this code:

```
SELECT 
Name
,Code
,MAX(Date)
,MAX(Value) AS Total 
FROM Department 
GROUP BY 
Name
,Code
```

Obviously, the issue with this is that I don't want to get just the MAX date, but I don't know how to include the Date in the output without using it in the `GROUP BY`. As a result, I'm only getting the results for each department with the latest date, in the case of multiple rows with the same department only one is included.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  With MySQL 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2.2+, you can use window functions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
code VARCHAR(100) NULL,
date DATETIME NULL,
Value INT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES('Finance', 'ABC12', '2020-05-12', 15);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES('Finance', 'ABC12', '2020-06-24', 118);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES('Marketing', 'BBG43', '2020-05-12', 12);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES('Marketing', 'BBG43', '2021-08-07', 1);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES('Tech', 'PKY76', '2020-07-21', 7);
INSERT INTO Department VALUES('Tech', 'PKY76', '2020-11-28', 7);


SELECT D.Name, D.Code, D.Date, T.MAX_VALUE 
FROM Department D
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Name,Code,MAX(Value) AS MAX_VALUE 
FROM Department 
GROUP BY Name,Code
) T ON D.CODE=T.CODE AND D.Value = T.MAX_VALUE;
```

And in future please share the create table and insert scripts. It is easy for us to provide solution.

Comment: @kikiz please upvote too so that it can help others